# add simple geometric elements to GUIDE GUI

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide

I am desiging a simple GUI application in Matlab using GUIDE.

I am displayed a number of axis - and I would like to add some simple design elements to make the interface clearer. I would like to draw a colored rectangle around an axis (seperate from the axis)... there are two such axes, each displaying details of some things shown in a third plot, and I would like this color clue to link the details to the overview.

So is it possible to add simple geometric shape objects to a Matlab GUI? I don't see anything but controls in GUIDE but perhaps its possible to add them manually with an explicit command?

Comment: Quick and dirty solution: Put each axis inside a panel with BorderType=line, BorderWidth=as big as you like, Title=[] and change the HighlightColor. Or use BorderType=None and an appropriate BackgroundColor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is generally difficult to draw any random shape. Except Square & rectangle, for which you can create panels and change the properties like BorderWidth and HighlightColor.

Since MATLAB GUI is based on Java, you can create any object in MATLAB GUI which can be created in Java. You can refer to this website [1] for further learning.

[1] http://undocumentedmatlab.com/matlab-java-book/